# How to add facet to the query (solr)

Tags: ezpublish, ezplatform

I can't add facets to the query. I try

```
$query = new Query;
$query->facetBuilders = [ new \eZ\Publish\API\Repository\Values\Content\Query\FacetBuilder\FieldFacetBuilder];


services:
  myservice:
     class: mynamespace\FacetHandler
     tags:
       - {name: ezpublish.search.solr.content.facet_builder_visitor}
```

And I have got the error "Intentionally not implemented: No visitor available for: eZ\Publish\API\Repository\Values\Content\Query\FacetBuilder\FieldFacetBuilder"

Also I have tried tag "ezpublish.search.solr.content.facet_builder_visitor.aggregate"

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you are required to hand over the field you want to apply the facet on.
In your case it might look like this:

```
$query = new Query;
$query->facetBuilders = [ new \eZ\Publish\API\Repository\Values\Content\Query\FacetBuilder\FieldFacetBuilder(
    [
        'fieldPaths' => 'article/title'
    ]
)];
```

"article" is the type-identifier of the class to filter by. I have yet to try if you can actually use it without a class-limitation.
"title" defines the field-identifier to use for the facet.

You may also use `regex` or `sort` (in addition to the `fieldPaths`-key to filter and sort the result.
The possible values for `sort` are listed as constants in the `FieldFacetBuilder`-class

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your field class as below

```
parameters:
    ezpublish.search.solr.query.content.facet_builder_visitor.field.class: Your\Bundle\Query\Content\FacetBuilderVisitor\Field
```

Define your service as below:

```
ezpublish.search.solr.query.content.facet_builder_visitor.field:
    class: "%ezpublish.search.solr.query.content.facet_builder_visitor.field.class%"
    tags:
        - {name: ezpublish.search.solr.query.content.facet_builder_visitor}
```

Implement your class

```
<?php

/**
 *
 */
namespace Your\Bundle\Query\Content\FacetBuilderVisitor;

use EzSystems\EzPlatformSolrSearchEngine\Query\FacetBuilderVisitor;
use eZ\Publish\API\Repository\Values\Content\Query\FacetBuilder;
use eZ\Publish\API\Repository\Values\Content\Search\Facet;

/**
 * Visits the Field facet builder.
 */
class Field extends FacetBuilderVisitor
{
    /**
     * CHeck if visitor is applicable to current facet result.
     *
     * @param string $field
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canMap($field)
    {
        return $field === 'field_id';
    }

    /**
     * Map Solr facet result back to facet objects.
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return Facet
     */
    public function map($field, array $data)
    {
        return new Facet\FieldFacet(
            array(
                'name' => 'field',
                'entries' => $this->mapData($data),
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check if visitor is applicable to current facet builder.
     *
     * @param FacetBuilder $facetBuilder
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canVisit(FacetBuilder $facetBuilder)
    {
        return $facetBuilder instanceof FacetBuilder\FieldFacetBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Map field value to a proper Solr representation.
     *
     * @param FacetBuilder $facetBuilder;
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function visit(FacetBuilder $facetBuilder)
    {
        return array(
            'facet.field' => 'field_id',
            'f.field_id.facet.limit' => $facetBuilder->limit,
            'f.field_id.facet.mincount' => $facetBuilder->minCount,
        );
    }
}
```

No more exception now ;) But does not work :'( https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Browsing%2C+finding%2C+viewing#Browsing,finding,viewing-PerformingaFacetedSearch